# What are the risks of installing nvidia driver 460 on unsupported card?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, hybrid-graphics, gpu-driver

I installed `nvidia-driver-460` from ubuntu repositories with apt which doesn't support my graphics card **Nvidia Quadro K3100M** for which **driver version 390** is recommended. I did this to solve a couple of issues with shotcut and obs-studio. I expected my system wouldn't boot after doing this. However, everything seems to be ok. And my question is what are the risks? Should I go back to version 390? I have a btrfs system snap shot just before I installed the newer driver.

Comment: Did installing this driver fix what ever problem you were trying to fix?

Comment: Yes, obs-studio didn't support hardware encoding, I wasn't even starting on the on demand power mode. Shotcut didn't also detect nvenc. It's all now solved.